# Subset data to remove data with incomplete months

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data frame `df` that I would like to break into `10-day` intervals. I would like to only use individuals within a given year that have complete months (e.g., 01-01-2011 - 01-31-2021). How could I filter the data to only include those with the "complete" data?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("15-06-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)



int <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(new) %>%
  group_split()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this by year or by month- here I've gone by month. Base data- a modified version of your input:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Build base dataframe
date <- seq.Date(dmy("15-06-2010"), dmy("20-12-2013"), by = "days")
id <- rep(seq(1, 5), each = length(date))
df_raw <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 id)
```

Drop a few values to 'break' up a year or two to proof the code later

```
set.seed(1234)
drop_rows <- sapply(sample(1:nrow(df_raw), 3), function(i) {
  return(i:(i+100))
}, simplify = FALSE) %>% unlist()

df <- df_raw[-c(drop_rows), ]
```

See what the data look like with these breaks:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = id, col = factor(id), group = id)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%Y-%b") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = ymd(paste0(2011:2014, "-01-01")))
```

[image]

Looks like there are complete years for:

- id 1: 2011
- id 2: 2011, 2012
- id 3: 2012
- id 4: 2011, 2012
- id 5: 2011, 2012

Identify those spans with dplyr grouping:

```
df %>%
  # Assign a year and month value for simplicity
  mutate(
    yr = year(date),
    mon = month(date),
    ) %>%
  
  # Summarize for a grouping of id, year, and month to get group length
  group_by(id, yr, mon) %>%
  summarise(days_measured_n = n()) %>%
  
  # Compare the actual days in each month to the days recorded
  mutate(
    actual_days_in_mon = lubridate::days_in_month(ymd(paste(yr, mon, "01", sep = "-"))),
    all_days_inc = days_measured_n == actual_days_in_mon
    ) %>%
  
  # Ungroup to base level, then regroup by id and year and see which id~year groupings
  # have ALL TRUE values in the n-days-per-month-recorded == n-days-per-month-expected 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id, yr) %>%
  summarise(
    all_months_correct = all(all_days_inc)
  ) %>%
  filter(all_months_correct)
```

Output matches expected based on figure above:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [5]
     id    yr all_months_correct
  <int> <dbl> <lgl>             
1     1  2011 TRUE              
2     2  2011 TRUE              
3     2  2012 TRUE              
4     3  2012 TRUE              
5     4  2011 TRUE              
6     4  2012 TRUE              
7     5  2011 TRUE              
8     5  2012 TRUE
```